# Docker mongo permissions issue with shared volume

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have a Mongo docker container where I have a shared volume with the host. I want a shared volume because I want to backup the data.

All works fine but shared volume is locked so I can't run backup scripts.

Here is my docker-compose file.

```
version: '3'
services:
  database:
    image: 'mongo'
    container_name: 'mongo-db'
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
    volumes:
      - ./init-mongo.js:/docker-entrypoint-inititdb.d/init-mongo.js:ro
      - /media/storage/Backup_Optiplex/mongo-volume:/data/db
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    command: mongod --bind_ip_all
    restart: always
```

Here is the init-mongo.js script, in case that is also relevant:

```
db.createUser(
    {
        user: "admin",
        pwd: "pass",
        roles:[
            {
                role: "root"
            }
        ]
    }
)
```

The shared volume is locked, so I can't run my backup software on it. Can someone advise?

Comment: can you please share what commands you ran to backup the data and the errors you faced? Seems like the backup needs to read the data and there should be no issues to back it up

Comment: I’m currently using syncthing to share the folder. There’s a permissions error in syncthing. Also I see the files locked when I browse to the folder in Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I'd run `syncthing` with elevated permissions so that it can read mongo data folder.

You can also try to modify the permissions on mongo data folder recursively after stopping mongo (and starting it again after the change), but that may be dangerous and not always work.